# I dont want to let user click in a tab in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, mat-tab

```
      <nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel" mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start">
              <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.route" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [disabled]='!rla.isActive' [active]="rla.isActive">{{ link.label | translate }}</a>
            </nav>
```

i still can click in a tab and navigate to that route . I have button "Next" to go in next tab and i dont want to can click in a tab and navigate to them..

Comment: Can you give more context and format your code correctly so it's more readable? Maybe also a screenshot of your HTML result?